# recursive method for exponent of a fixed power

Tags: java, methods, recursion

Is it possible to create a recursive method that takes a single int as a parameter and returns the passed int to the power of 10?

this is what I have so far, but I get StackOverFlow error:

```
public static int exponent(int baseNum) {                       

   return baseNum * exponent(baseNum); 

}
```

Comment: You're missing a base case. And your recursion is not correct. You'd want to create a helper method.

Comment: ofcourse you'd get SOE cuz you never declared your base condition

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to tell the recursive function when to stop recursing.  It'll just go forever, which is why you get a stack error.

```
public static int exponent(int baseNum, int exp) {
   if (exp == 0)
       return 1;
   else
       return baseNum * exponent(baseNum, --exp); 
}
```

Now you can get 32^10 by calling:

```
exponent(32, 10);
```

And if you want a specialized function to raise a number to the power of ten then you can overload the exponent method:

```
public static int exponent(int baseNum) {
   return exponent(baseNum, 10); 
}
```

Only works with exponent values >= 0, of course.

Comment: can this method be done for a fixed power? The method must take a single parameter of int "baseNum" and return "baseNum^10".

Comment: use `exponent(x)`.  It will call `exponent(x, 10)`.

Comment: where should I use exponent(x)? I can't do that with two parameters.

Comment: If you want to raise 12 to the tenth power, you can just use `exponent(12);`